# Entity framework move/archive data from one database to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I have the following scenario:

I have a production database which is highly transactional. In order to keep queries efficient  I would like to archive data from some of the tables to another database with exactly the same schema.

The relationships between tables are not very complex but any dependent objects would have to go with the archived data in order to uphold foreign key constraints.

Is there a simple way to do this using Entity Framework? I have tried to create two different contexts and add to one and delete from the other, but this is a bit of a tedious route.

If Entity Framework is not the best tool for this what is?

Comment: Under what conditions would you want to archive data? Data that's too old gets archived at some threshold? Data that gets deleted gets archived? etc.

Comment: You could build something in SSIS using a whole bunch of business logic, but the proper way to do this is (most likely) with partitioning.  It has a host of pros and cons to weigh, however.  Consult a DBA and maybe a BI developer.

Comment: @Ocelot20 I have some complex queries on the transactional data using EF. There are millions of rows and the queries are becoming slow. Even with proper indexing. I would like to archive data older than X months to a separate location to try speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way in EF5 to do this.

If your database is MSSQL you can make use of partitioning for archive tables (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/02/14/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-1-the-basics.aspx for more information).

Comment: I am not sure that EF queries are optimised to not look for data in other partitions. There is a cost for querying across partitions.